# Splitting class file

Tags: php

I've got config.class  file which is getting bigger and bigger.
It has structure like this:

```
class config
{
    public $myConfig = 20;
    ....

    public __construct() {
        $this->set_config_topics();
        ....
    }

    private function set_config_topics() {
        $this->bum='gg';
        ....
    }
}
```

I want to split that config class to several config files (module config).
I can extend class but I don't want to get wierd chain.
I want something like this:

```
class config
{
    private config_files=array(
        'config.topics.php',
        'config.second.module.php',
        ...
    );

    public __construct() {
        //require all config_files and attach them as class' variables
    }
}
```

How to do it?

Comment: If there's going to be so much config that it requires multiple files to be managed, would it not be better to have a database config file, and then load any other config from the database on startup, or get them as required?  That way if you create the config and forget to add the file to the config class, the values will be loaded from the DB and not missed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're in a newer version of PHP (5.4+), you can use [traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php).

```php
trait ConfigTopics {
    protected function set_config_topics() {
        // ...
    }
}

class config {
    use ConfigTopics;

    public __construct() {
        $this->set_config_topics();
    }
}
```

Some notes:

- If you are inheriting non-public methods, they should be `protected` rather than `private`. This is because `private` methods can only be accessed from the class/trait where they are actually defined, but `protected` methods can also be used by all sub-classes.
- Traits are useful for sharing common code/functionality between multiple different classes. If none of these functions are used outside of your config class, then I really wouldn't bother splitting them out. Instead try an editor which supports code folding, or something like that.
- You can also extend a class (i.e. a sub-class). You can only extend one class, though, so traits are a type of multiple-inheritance for functionality.